# Resizing pgf plots in an A0 beamer poster

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, beamerposter

I am creating a A0 scientific poster with the `beamerposter` package and I want to include TikZ/PGF plots. However, if I typeset these plots, the line width for the axis and for the data are too small. The data points are also too small.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[orientation=portrait, size=a0, scale=1]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

What the default is:

\scalebox{1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot coordinates {(2, 0) (1, 1) (0, 2)};
        \addlegendentry{Legend}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

Best solution yet:

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \begin{axis}[ticklabel style={font=\tiny},legend style={font=\tiny}]
        \addplot coordinates {(2, 0) (1, 1) (0, 2)};
        \addlegendentry{Legend}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Cropped solution]

Does anyone know a fix? What am I missing here?

EDIT: better example, with a sort-of-fix inspired by percusse's answer.
EDIT2: best solution yet, thanks to percusse.

Comment: If all you want is change the line width (not the size of the plot itself), you can try `\begin{axis}[line width=.2ex]`. Adjust the value to suit your needs.

Comment: tikz puts special care into not changing linewidths or font sizes when different scale is used in a tikzpicture. This isthe right thing to do for a standard document, but perhaps not adequate for a poster, which has to be designed to be seen from a bigger distance. I would generate the plot in a different (a4) document, and then include the resulting pdf into your poster using `\includegraphics` and changing the scale/size with this command.

Comment: @Jubobs I don't want to change only the linewidth, I would like the whole plot to keep the same appearance as in an article or a beamer document, where the linewidth is larger among other things.

Comment: @JLDiaz That is one solution (using the standalone class with sans-serif font), but it's not quite practical, and I was hoping there was a more normal and automatic solution.

Comment: @aha-a-yellow You can use `canvas transform={scale=whatever}`, but that would produce wrong bounding boxes, since tikz loses track of coordinates under canvas transformations. So I really think that the best option is the "standalone" figure and `\includegraphics`

Comment: @JLDiaz The problem with the standalone is that the dimensions of the produced figure are wrong. It seems to be a little more than twice as small: if I use `\includegraphics[scale=2]{plot}`, the font size is still slightly smaller than the rest of the text. I guess this has something to do with the beamerposter package. Trial and error could get me to find the correct scaling ratio, but it's not an ideal solution.

Comment: If you copy the the axis options to the first picture and add `[scale=2]` to the tikzpicture environment, they look pretty similar,.

Comment: What you're probably looking for is a combination of percusse's suggestion to use `scale` and Jubobs's suggestion to set the line width. You can set the line width and font sizes globally using something like `\pgfplotsset{ticklabel style={font=\tiny},legend style={font=\tiny}, every axis/.append style={line width=.75 pt}}`.

Comment: @aha-a-yellow, if this is resolved, would you care to write a self-answer?

Answer (score 1):

The size doesn't actually change but only the fonts create an illusion together with the legend box. Modifying the font style or adding a style to your plots makes it identical. Here is with and without `beamerposter` comparison

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait, size=a0]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Text here.


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ticklabel style={font=\tiny},legend style={font=\tiny}]
        \addplot coordinates {(2, 0) (1, 1) (0, 2)};
        \addlegendentry{Legend}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wait did I get the question wrong?

Comment: It's the other way around, I'd like to get the same appearance (on beamerposter) that I get in a normal beamer.

Comment: Actually your fix combined with `\scalebox{2}{}` pretty much does the trick, even though the scaling factor is probably 2.1 or 2.2 or something.

Comment: @percusse Based on the last comment, could you perhaps modify this answer so we can get a question off the unanswered list ;-)